# How can I work around my column names needing to be longer than what's allowed in SQL?

Tags: php, sql, html, phpmyadmin

I've encountered a bit of a situation with creating my sql database.  I've been working on a Questionnaire that has tons of questions.  I'm using a PHP script that automatically creates the table when a user submits the questionnaire and it uses the input names to name the columns of the table.

I figured a good way to keep everything easy for me to follow later on when I review submissions is to use the questions as the name attribute for the HTML inputs so that when I query it everything is right there and I don't have to wonder which answer goes to which question or go back and forth looking at something else.

The problem I ran into is there's a limit to how long the names of SQL columns can be.  I'm not sure of exactly how long that is but I ran into an error until I shortened the input names.

So what I need to accomplish is using shorter names for the inputs so they're not too long for the sql columns, but somehow link it to another table that consists of the actual names so they can be queried later on when I need to go over a submission.  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Creates the table as in, if it doesn't exist, right? Also, I wonder if there's a way to [map](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) the fields to column names...

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Wouldn't this mean you would have spaces in  the column names? Like: "What color is your car?"

Comment: @theB that would be correct.  foxbeefly I ws intending to do "What_color_is_our_car" to eliminate the spaces, but seeing that it's not going to work due to the length of some of the questions I have to find a workaround.  More like giving it a name like "Ques_01" and having it link to something that would allow me to Query "What color is your car?" instead of "Ques_01, Ques_02,Ques_03" so I actually know what they're answering without having to look at something else simultaneously.

Comment: The way to do this is not to create tables dynamically. Use more generic tables and store the data as actual data in those tables. If you give us an example of your tables, we can provide an alternative which will be much easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: As indicated by others.....the usage of the column NAMES is not intended to be to store questions but instead names for columns with the fields themselves in a row then having the questions and answers respectively. From what I read you seem to have a bit of a lets call it interesting idea of how tables and columns should be used (in contrast to how it is intended by database engines that they are used). Can you perhaps give a few examples and infos like: How many answers are there max. for a specific question and are the same answers possible for multiple questions,... ? We could help you!

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. The way to approach this problem is to store data as data, inside the actual columns, rather than dynamically generate tables and column names.

For example, for a user-generated questionnaire, you might have this layout:

## Users table:

```
id name
 1 john
 2 alice
 3 fred
```

## Questionnaire Table:

```
id created_by_user_id questionnaire_name
 1 1                  Animal Questionnaire
 2 3                  Tree Questionnaire
 ...
```

## Questions Table:

```
id questionnaire_id question
 1 1                How many pets do you own?
 2 1                Have you ever owned a goldfish?
 3 1                Do you like cows?
 4 2                How many trees are in your back yard?
 5 2                When did you last see a silver birch?
 ...
```

## Answers table

```
 id questionnaire_id question_id user_answered_id answer_text
  1                1           1                2 Four
  2                1           2                2 No
  3                1           3                2 I love cows!
  4                1           3                3 I hate cows.
```

This way you only need one table per type of fact, you don't have to generate tables or columns dynamically, and you can store as much text as you like for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the maximum length is 128 characters, but there are exceptions depending on what version of SQL you are using.

Comment: hmm... well I have a few that go over 128 characters, so I'd still need a workaround.

Comment: You could populate the first row of the table with the questions.